# Error using webclient with gmail

Tags: exception, io, gmail, webclient

This is the code:

```
response =
    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
       objClient.DownloadData("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom")
    );
```

And this is the error (exception) I get:
WebClient does not support current i/o operation

what could be the reason for that exception?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error you're talking about is "WebClient does not support **con**current I/O operations".

This exception is caused when you try to make multiple requests at the same time from a single WebClient instance. If you want to make concurrent requests, create a new WebClient instance.